# RSpec Post Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to understand why my rspec test isnt working while my actual code to create a new record is.

The error I get is: Failure/Error:

```
expect {
   post "/products/", params: {product: attributes_for(:product)}, as: :json
}.to change(Product, :count).by(1)

expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

I tried to actually use the code and it appears to add a new record, but I'm not quite sure why the test is not working. Have I written the test incorrectly?

ProductsController

```
def create
  @p = Product.new(product_params)
  @p.save
  redirect_to action: :new
end
```

Product < ApplicationRecord

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true #--- Presence
  validates :title, length: { minimum: 2 } #--- Minimum 2
  validates :title, :description, length: { maximum: 1000 } #--- Maximum 1000
end
```

ProductSpec

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'pp'

RSpec.describe "ProductsRequests", type: :request do
  #--- New
  describe "#new" do
    context "logged in as guest" do
      before :each do
        get new_product_path
      end

      it { expect(assigns(:p)).to be_a_new(Product) }
      it { expect(response).to render_template :new }
    end#--- Guest New
  end #--- New

  #--- Create
  describe "#create" do
    context "logged in as guest" do
       it "creates new record" do 
        expect{
          post "/products/", params: {product: attributes_for(:product)}
        }.to change(Product, :count).by(1) 
      end

    end #--- Guest Create
  end #--- Create
```

Comment: In your Products controller - add some logging so you can see the params that get passed through and whether the `@p` is actually saved eg after `@p.save` put: `puts "for params: #{params.inspect} we have errors? #{@p.errors.inspect}"`

Comment: Show us your `Product` factory definition

Comment: `require 'faker'
FactoryBot.define do
  
  factory :product do
    title {Faker::Commerce.product_name } 
    description {Faker::Commerce.product_name }
  end`

Answer (score 0):

**The quickest way to debug it would be to change `save` into `save!` in your controller.**

`save` tries to save, and returns false if it fails so you probably want to use it and add some handling later (errors are in `@p.errors`), but for now to quickly see what's going on use `save!` - it raises an exception if anything (including validations) goes wrong.

Comment: The controller works, it can see the new records in the database when I visit action: :index, but for some reason the test itself isn't working.

Comment: Yeah, it works through browser but it doesn't work through specs, my method is the fastest way to check what's wrong (either you get the exception = win, or don't and you should check routes etc.). Did you try it?